# Using roman numerals for \volcite in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, citing, roman-numerals

I would like to submit an article to a journal that requires all references to volumes to appear in roman numerals before the page reference, e.g.:

William Shakespeare, *Complete Works*, III, 25.

For the regular 'volume' field, a simple

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\RN{#1}}
```

can takes care of this. This does not affect `\volcite` and related commands, however. I am far from an expert, and don't know how to go about this. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to begin your questions with a greeting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What follows is a hack with possible adverse effects.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}

% For biblatex <=1.5a
% \makeatletter
% \patchcmd{\blx@volcite@vol}{\ppspace#1}{\ppspace\RN{#1}}{}{}
% \makeatother

% For biblatex >=1.6
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitevolume}{\bibstring{volume}\ppspace\RN{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest.bib}
@book{Sha,
  author={Shakespeare, William},
  title={Complete Works},
  date={1590/1611},
  volumes={99},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatextest.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \avolcite{3}[25]{Sha}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Solution updated for biblatex 1.6, which introduced formatting hooks for `\volcite` & friends.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. No clean solution, of course, but works for me!

Comment: I think you're being too cautious in saying that this may have adverse side effects. It's not really a hack; it's just that `biblatex` doesn't seem to have provided a hook for this case. I don't see any problems that could arise through this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this construction: `\avolcite{III}[25]{Sha}`

Comment: This way, if you decide later that you don't like Roman numerals, you will have to hunt down and manually change every occurence of `\avolcite`.

Comment: Certainly, but the first answer suggested _possible adverse effects,_ and this has none. Should a reversal be required, any reasonable text editor should be able easily to find all occurrences that need changing, and many can be used to automate the change.